# Trying to add order total to WooCommerce new order email subject line

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add order total to the new order email subject line.

I tried the following but it did not work (just the placeholder was visible in email subject line).

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Thanks

Following placeholder added to email subject line in woo > settings > email > new order

`{order_total}`

Following added to function.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'add_custom_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    // The post meta key used to save the value in the order post meta data
    $meta_key = '_order_total';

    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order    = $email->object;

    // Get the value
    $value = $order->get_meta($meta_key) ? $order->get_meta($meta_key) : '';

    // Additional subject placeholder
    $new_placeholders = array( '{order_total}' => $value );

    // Return the clean replacement value string for "{order_total}" placeholder
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RE: https://woocommerce.com/document/change-email-subject-lines/

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);

function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $meta_key = '_order_total';

    $value = $order->get_meta($meta_key) ? $order->get_meta($meta_key) : '';

    $subject = sprintf(
        '[%s] New Customer Order %s (# %s) from Name %s %s', 
        $blogname, 
        $value,
        $order->id, 
        $order->billing_first_name, 
        $order->billing_last_name
    );

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: You can use `$order->get_total()` instead of `$order->get_meta('_order_total')`

Comment: thanks - I added to functions.php and ran test purchase

admin email for new order subject line did not change.

any ideas?

Comment: several things could be happening then, is the new email enabled, try setting priority to -1 and put some debug in there to see it fire, if not dbl dbl check that new emails are enabled; Check that nothing else is envoking woocommerce_email_subject_new_order after yours